# How to draw a network using pairs of coordinates

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a string:

```
MULTILINESTRING (
    (0 0, 0 20),
    (20 0, 20 20),
    (7.49080237694725 11.97316968394073, 5.67208473076472 5.229834926470677),
    (19.01428612819832 3.12037280884873, 25.96681259449994 4.024633854021577),
    (14.6398788362281 3.119890406724053, 21.51766222234933 1.803845175041164)
)
```

which I like to draw, by that I meant I want to connect every set of pairs, lets say connect `(0 0, 0 20)` together, connecting `(0 0)` to `(0 20)` and so on.

I prefer a kind of for loop rather than just separate them into different lines and connecting them. 
also it is important for me to use Networkx since later on I want to find some matrix such as adjacent matrix.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, we have a string:

```
import networkx as nx
import re

a = """MULTILINESTRING (
    (0 0, 0 20),
    (20 0, 20 20),
    (7.49080237694725 11.97316968394073, 5.67208473076472 5.229834926470677),
    (19.01428612819832 3.12037280884873, 25.96681259449994 4.024633854021577),
    (14.6398788362281 3.119890406724053, 21.51766222234933 1.803845175041164)
)"""
```

Firstly we construct a regex to extract all coordinates from the string:

```
REGEX = re.compile(r'\((?P<x1>[\d\.]+) (?P<y1>[\d\.]+), (?P<x2>[\d\.]+) (?P<y2>[\d\.]+)\)')
raw_coords = REGEX.findall(a)
```

We extracted strings instead of floats. Moreover, they are not in Networkx-compatible format. So we reformat them:

```
coords = [
    [(float(c[0]), float(c[1])), (float(c[2]), float(c[3]))]
    for c in raw_coords
]
```

Create the graph and fill it with our edges (it will create nodes with coordinates automatically):

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(coords)
```

Create the position dict (needed for `nx.draw`):

```
pos = {n: n for n in G.nodes}
```

Create the label dict (for beautiful drawing):

```
labels = {n: '({:.2f}, {:.2f})'.format(n[0], n[1]) for n in G.nodes}
```

And draw the final graph:

```
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=pos,
    labels=labels
)
```

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers. this is what I was looking for. Do you know by any chance how can I do the following:1- Get rid of arrows 2- The last two vertical lines are always in my data and I want them with different color than others

Comment: Check `draw_networkx` function: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx , especially `arrows` and `edge_color` parameters.